# ¿Cómo evitar ser hackeado?

Tags: wordpress

Buenas, resulta que tengo que revisar unas webs hechas en wordpress, y nada más entrar en sus archivos en muchas de ellas encuentro estos archivos, uno de ellos o los dos. Se llamana `kontlo.php` y `king.php.php` El contenido es el siguinete:

```html
<html>
<head>

<title>Hacked ?? IDBTE4M ?? WHO CARE</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://facebook.com/fp.idbte4m/">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fauna+One" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.riwilepriware.com/idb.jpg"></link>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="kefiex404">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<meta name="description" content="kefiex404">
<meta content="hacked" name="description"/>
<meta content="go.id,defacer,hacked,hacker,news,idbte4m,never die" name="keywords"/>
<meta content="INDEX, FOLLOW" name="ROBOTS"/>
<meta content="riwilepriware.com" name="author"/>
<body bgcolor="#000" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background: black  no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size:cover;" onload="(function(a){window.CloudFlare &amp;&amp; window.CloudFlare.push(function(b){b([&quot;cloudflare/rocket&quot;],function(c){c.push(function(){(function(){type_text()}).call(a)})})})})(this);" bottommargin="0" rightmargin="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0">
<style>body{font-family:"courier new";font-size:80%;color:#28FE14;}.xBody{width:660px;height:450px;position:absolute;z-index:9;}.ssh{display:none;z-index:9;}.sshBox{height:300px;border:4px solid white;-moz-border-radius:4px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;-o-border-radius:4x;-khtml-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;z-index:9;}.sshHead{margin-bottom:5px;color:black;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;height:20px;z-index:9;}.greenBox{padding-left:3px;position:absolute;height:22px;border:1px solid #28FE14;z-index:9;}.picz{position:absolute;width:500px;height:80%;display:none;right:2px;top:2px;}#mg img:hover{-webkit-animation:tremer 0.5s linear infinite;-moz-animation:tremer 0.5s linear infinite;-o-animation:tremer 0.5s linear infinite;animation:tremer 0.5s linear infinite;}.neon{<!--coleur lootz--> color:blue;text-shadow:0 0 5px red,0 0 10px red,0 0 30px orange,0 0 45px yellow,0 0 60px red;}.like{border:4px double yellow;box-shadow:0px 2px 20px white;border-radius:10px;padding:9px;height:310px;}#mg img{border:4px double yellow;border-radius:10px;opacity:0.75;-moz-opacity:0.75;filter:alpha(opacity=75);}</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">

<center>

<body onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false" onLoad="(function(a){window.CloudFlare &amp;&amp; window.CloudFlare.push(function(b){b([&quot;cloudflare/rocket&quot;],function(c){c.push(function(){(function(){writetext()}).call(a)})})})})(this);">
<center> 
<font face="iceland" color="red">
<center>
<div id="mg">
<center><a title="KEFIEX404"> <p class="style5"><div align="center"><table width="100%"border="0 "><tr><td align="left"><img src="http://zonehmirrors.org/defaced/2016/11/11/alignlifewauwatosa.com/kefiex.yu.tl/files/bnx.png" height="150" width="250"/ </td><br /> 
<td align="center"> <img src="http://omahunduh.com/omahunduh.com.jpg" alt="Omah Unduh" height="150" width="250"></td><br />
<td align="right"><img src="http://www.riwilepriware.com/idb.jpg" height="150" width="250"/ ></td></tr></table></
</div></p></center>
<br>

<td width="90%"><font color="aqua" size="4">
-=| WE NOT ONLY TE4M BUT WE ARE FAMILY |=-<br>
<br><td width="90%"><font color="aqua" size="4">
DEFACER TERSAKITI TEAM | HACKER SAKIT HATI | PASUKAN BERANI MATI | BOCAH NEWBIE | MADLEETS <br> IDCA | CIREBON CYBER TEAM | MALANG CYBER ARMY | BALIKITA TEAM | SANJUNGAN JIWA <br> KONTOL MIBER | JEMBUT NGRIWUL | PEJUH MUNCRAT | DADI ANAK  
<BR><br>
<font color="red">-= WE ARE THE TROUBLE MAKER =- </font><br>
<marquee><code><font color="blue" face="consolas" size="4">
<p align="left" class="style2"><font face="Trajan Pro" size="4" color="RED" style="text-shadow: 2px 0px .2em aqua, -2px 2px .2em Darkcyan, -2px -2px .2em black"><b><font color="yellow"> 
~ ./KEFIEX404 ~ KONSLET ~ MANIAK KASUR ~ MR.K ~ EL-RO ~ ANTONIO HsH ~ TUAN GALAU ~ DEDEMIT ID ~ NO SCRIPT 404 ~ K3C0T ~ SIM0D ~ Anton Kill ~ LITLE H4XORZ ~ ANDRIF PZF ~ Syntax-Error ~ FadliDotID_007 ~ SANEKALA ~ YUDHI DM ~ TUSBOLLED~ ALL INDOXPLOIT CREW ~ SHOR7CUT ~ GRETZ IDBTE4M ~ GOENK TEA ~ ./HDV ~ ADRIAN XDA ~ DIDOT ~ POETRA D`M ~ JACK D`RIPPER ~ 
 DAY IDBTE4M ~ DIMAZ BN ~ DEMONK ~ KHUNAY ~ MR-AQ ~ HENDRA D`N ~ PETAPA GENIT ~ KODRAT ~ MUZZAM ~ MAULANA ~ SIRIN ~ ~ X-Wu7z ~ Tuan_galau ~ GrenXPaRTa ~ x"1n73ct ~ m@db100d ~ Hacker Sakit Hati ~ ./$amndan404 ~ ./wi.na ~ Neneng Juhairiah ~ Mr_Oxygen ~ ./coco ~ H3ri.ID ~ Ice Cream ~ newbie patah hati ~ Naughty_r00tz ~ DarkWireless ~ ./czw_07 ~ ./TanpaNama404 ~ xCut10n ~ Kucing Galau ~ ./anjirGBX ~ Dicky Injector ~ jepry_vuln ~ Shut_Down404 ~ Mr.404_NotFound ~ Mr.LittleHaxor ~ Mr.Ghostteror_404 ~ Mr.Dork ~ Mr.aji.192 ~ L4W_CyberDKSH404.Not_Found ~ ozlok ~ Bloc_Anon/404 ~ R3DD3V1L ~ mr.cookie_302 ~ @HF404_  
~ S4bun ~ WokTampan ~ Ozi L0calhost ~ isal dot id ~ pys404 ~ tomhawk ~ Localhost ~ Dhammashoka1337 ~ Dreamless ~ Ambara Cyber Army ~ CarLi ~ /AwKarin ~ ./Kandani ~ s4bun ~ ./BlaDDzeRR ~ bL@cKID ~ Mr.Vendetta_404 ~ ./Kandasx1337 ~ ./94nt3n9 ~ SkumFuk-45 ~ LukeWalker ~ R1W1l 3PR1W4R3 ~ D9ncX ~  AND YOU ~ </font></code></marquee>
<br>
<strong>-+ IDBTE4M AREA GALAU RAMARIMARI +-</strong>
</td>
</center>
<br> <br></span></div>
```

Y el contenido del segundo es este:

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<center><font color=green size =13><html>
<head><title>
HaCkEd By RxR HaCkEr
</title>
<body>
<body bgcolor="black">
<center>

 </center>
<div dir="ltr" align="center"> 


<img src="http://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-7427d1057b67b1e6f59900b9453dbb81-c"><br><font color =red size=5><br >HaCkEd By RxR HaCkEr <br> Skype:a.789a<br>icq:728196843  <br><font color =white size=5>
<iframe width="0%" height="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F101962726&amp;color=ff6600&amp;auto_play=true&amp;show_artwork=true"></iframe>
  <a href="http://facebook.com/RxRHaCk">Contact Me </a>


</body>
</html>
```

Esto me lo encuentro en casi todas las webs del servidor, cómo tengo que luchar contra esto? Es decir para que no vuelva a pasar. Los plugins de seguridad de WordPress no valen para nada, pues no detectan estos archivos, al menos no el primero, el segundo sí que lo detectan a veces.

Instalé `ClamAv`en mi servidor para escanearlo, halló 9 archivos y los eliminé, pero imagino que estos archivos no los detecta pues no so "virus" en realidad.

Supongo que toca eliminarlos uno por uno.

Pero la pregunta es:

**¿Cómo evito que vuelva a pasar?**

Comment: entras ala servidor desde cualquier red publica?

Comment: No, tan solo de la red privada. De hecho no utilizo redes públicas nunca, y mucho menos para acceder a mis cuentas privadas de cualquier cosa.

Comment: y configurates tu servidor para que solo se pueda acceder por esa via?

Comment: No, no lo hice, pero la contraseña del mismo se ha cambiado hace 1 día, y se cambia cada semana actualmente, y solo la conozco yo y mi jefe, por otra parte el servidor mismo bloquea las ip que pretenden entrar más de 3 veces fallidas.

Comment: Activa el firewall y configura bien :)

Comment: Pero como activo el firewall en un CentOS7? Qué parametros tengo que configurar para evitar este tipo de ataques y otros?

Comment: Ese tipo de intromisiones en WP son muy muy difíciles de detectar. Puede que haya diseminados en todo el WP más archivos infectados que seguirán haciendo su trabajo. Lo mejor es hacer una instalación nueva, recuperando: **A.** la base de datos (y revisándola minuciosamente) ,  **B.** posibles configuraciones que vayas a necesitar; **C.** archivos como imágenes... etc. Con todo el contenido, instalación nueva y establecer medidas de seguridad. Puedes instalar `clamav` y hacer un escaneo de todo el sistema.

Comment: Tengo `ClamAV` instalado en el servidor pero no detectó estos archivos, aunque detectó otros. Por otra parte las infectadas eran cerca de 200 páginas, simplemente no puedo reinstalar y reconfigurarlas todas ...

Comment: Pablo me temo que no podrás decir esto: *simplemente no puedo reinstalar y reconfigurarlas todas*. Yo me temo que sí, que debes revisar todo. Imaginemos que inviertes un gran esfuerzo en limpiar el sistema, pero dejas ciertas páginas infectadas sin revisar y las subes en la nueva instalación. Con una sola página infectada el virus seguirá propagándose. Es como dejar una manzana podrida en una cesta de manzanas buenas... al final se irán pudriendo todas. Toca revisar todo... o como se ha dicho en la respuesta, pagar a otros para que lo hagan por ti. Este tipo de infecciones son difíciles.

Comment: CloudFlare + WordFence + System Updated. Si cumples estos tres, es muy difícil que entren, a no ser que hablemos ya de gente profesional con un target específico. No obstante, el defacer es viejo y automático, probablemente no tengas el sistema actualizado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero sería cambiar las contraseñas de los usuarios FTP, el usuario de la base de datos, los usuarios SHELL y la de los usuarios del wordpress.

Después se pueden hacer muchas cosas como por ejemplo:

- Revisar los logs regularmente
- Crear reglas en el fichero hosts y/o hosts.deny para que los dominios detectados vayan a 0.0.0.0
- Suscribirte a reglas para hosts conocidas y ya bloqueadas como: http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt
- Instalar herramientas como fail2ban, rkhunter, snort y similares (para fail2ban, crear reglas para los login de wordpress)
- Activar SEClinux y iptables.
- Colocar bien los permisos de las carpetas y ficheros
- Crear un usuario de solo lectura en la base de datos si es posible y no se usan INSERTs y UPDATEs (en este punto, hay un proyecto interesante de Chema Alonso y su latch, también tienen un plugin para wordpres en su github https://github.com/ElevenPaths/latch-plugin-wordpress)
- Usar solo plugins actualizados y en el menor número posible.
- Usar themes actualizados y eliminar los que no usas (lo mismo con los plugins).
- Cambiar el nombre de usuario "admin" por defecto.
- Si puedes limitar los acceso a la parte administración por IP, mejor. Lo puedes hacer con el htaccess o iptables.
- Seguro que me dejo cosas, porque cada servidor es un mundo.

También puedes contratar una auditoría para que intenten reventar la web.

NOTA: Añado otro punto:

- Editar el fichero php.ini y deshabilitar estas funciones con:

  disable_functions = system, exec, popen, passthru, shell_exec, proc_close, proc_get_status, proc_nice, proc_open, proc_terminate

Comment: Muchas gracias, de hecho la mayoría de medidas las tengo aplicadas, pero como el ataque viene de antes de que trabajara yo en la empresa, me toca limpiar y asegurar las webs a mi...